# How to create new column based on values after "/" in other column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with "col1" in Oracle:

```
col1
------
email1.com/GGR2
pokmail.com/AA
rrajd.com.nl/RRe2
```

I need to create "col2" with values after "/". So as a result I need something like below:

```
col1              | col2
--------------------------
email1.com/GGR2   |GGR2
pokmail.com/AA    |AA
rrajd.com.nl/RRe2 |RRe2
```

How can I do that in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions or `substr` + `instr`:

```
SQL> with test (col1) as
  2    (select 'email1.com/GGR2' from dual union all
  3     select 'pokmail.com/AA'  from dual union all
  4     select 'rrajd.com.nl/RRe2' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1,
  7         regexp_substr(col1, '\w+$') col2_first,
  8         --
  9         substr(col1, instr(col1, '/') + 1) col2_second
 10  from test;

COL1              COL2_FIRST        COL2_SECOND
----------------- ----------------- -----------------
email1.com/GGR2   GGR2              GGR2
pokmail.com/AA    AA                AA
rrajd.com.nl/RRe2 RRe2              RRe2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       CASE INSTR(col1, '/')
       WHEN 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, '/') + 1)
       END AS col2
FROM   table_name;
```

or, using (slower) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '/(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS re_col2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1) AS
SELECT 'email1.com/GGR2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'pokmail.com/AA'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'rrajd.com.nl/RRe2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'example.com/ab/cd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'example.com'       FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | email1.com/GGR2 | GGR2 |
> | pokmail.com/AA | AA |
> | rrajd.com.nl/RRe2 | RRe2 |
> | example.com | ab/cd |
> | example.com |  |

*Notes:*

- This will work even if the column does not contain a `/` character.
- If you just use `SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, '/') + 1)` and the string does not contain `/` then it will return everything rather than returning `NULL`.
- If you use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '\w+$')` and the string either contains no or multiple `/` characters (or any other non-word characters) then it will not return the substring after the first `/`.

Comparing the outputs:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       CASE INSTR(col1, '/')
       WHEN 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, '/') + 1)
       END AS col2a,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '/(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS col2b,
       SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, '/') + 1) AS col2c,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '\w+$') AS col2d
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2A | COL2B | COL2C | COL2D |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | email1.com/GGR2 | GGR2 | GGR2 | GGR2 | GGR2 |
> | pokmail.com/AA | AA | AA | AA | AA |
> | rrajd.com.nl/RRe2 | RRe2 | RRe2 | RRe2 | RRe2 |
> | example.com/ab/cd | ab/cd | ab/cd | ab/cd | cd |
> | example.com |  |  | example.com | com |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f2ce2d0a755d7067ba3581bb0ad0eed)*